Is `ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY xml.node)` well defined?
While researching the answer to another question that required extracting XML nodes in the original element order, I came across several answers (here, here, and here) that used expressions of the form ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY xml.node), and asserted or implied that the assigned row number values would be assigned in XML document order.
However, I cannot find anywhere that defines the behavior of ORDER BY xml.node. Although it seems to be allowed in the OVER() clause, the documentation does not specifically mention XML nodes.
For example, given:
DECLARE @xml XML = '<root>
<node>One</node>
<node>Two</node>
<node>Three</node>
<node>Four</node>
</root>'

SELECT
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY xml.node) AS rn,
    xml.node.value('./text()[1]', 'varchar(255)') AS value
FROM @xml.nodes('*/node') xml(node)
ORDER BY
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY xml.node)

The following results are returned:
rn | value
----------
1  | One
2  | Two
3  | Three
4  | Four

Are these results guaranteed anywhere in the documentation? Or is this accepted as guaranteed, but undocumented behavior?  Or is this another case like ORDER BY (SELECT NULL) that seems to work anecdotally for small result sets, but may eventually fail when scaled up?
Interestingly, when used in an ordinary select order-by clause, ORDER BY xml.node yields the following error:

Msg 493 Level 16 State 1 Line 7
The column 'node' that was returned from the nodes() method cannot be used directly. It can only be used with one of the four XML data type methods, exist(), nodes(), query(), and value(), or in IS NULL and IS NOT NULL checks.

See this db<>fiddle.

Detailed SQL questions belong on https://dba.stackexchange.com/

@DaleK - I don't understand your reasoning. This seems more like a SQL programming question than a DBA question.

Check the "what to ask here page" (like we tell all the newbies on this site lol) and you'll see it includes things such as Advanced Querying, Advanced Programming (as applies to databases). While there are many experts here who know that stuff, there are more there.

I'd say its on topic for either site but if the question requires deep knowledge of the optimiser internals you'd probably want Paul White to answer it and the chances of that are much better on dba.se than Stackoverflow (the linked duplicate being an exception)

The main question "Are these results guaranteed anywhere in the documentation?" remains unanswered. I have reposted on DBA Stack Exchange here.
